# Import AI, EPS, and PDF files as images to FabricJS Canvas

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have gone through the docs for FabricJS and searched the Web, but don't see how I could add .ai, .eps, and .pdf files to the canvas akin to how a .png image is loaded into the canvas. Is it even possible, or are there any node.js or pure javascript tools I could use that would convert an .ai, .eps, or .pdf on upload to an image that can be used in the canvas?

Comment: I think FabricJS can only paint `<img>` element's content onto the canvas. .ai, .eps, and .pdf can not be loaded natively in <img> tags. [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) can load pdf files then export pages to png. So this workaround will work for .pdf and .ai files saved with the "create a pdf compatible file" option. For .eps, the only PostScript interpreter I've found is [WPS](http://logand.com/sw/wps/index.html) but I don't think you can pass Adobe's .eps into it.

Comment: Great suggestions. What about leveraging ImageMagik?

Comment: Yes, ImageMagick might be able to preprocess on the server those files and encode it to png http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php But you will need [GhostScript](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/) beside ImageMagick.